# How to change ssh default config name or location?

Tags: git, ssh

By default the ssh config file is ~/.ssh/config, but for some historical reason, there already have a directory ~/.ssh/config/, so I want to change the ssh config file name or location, so my ssh can pick the new config file up.

I already tried `ssh -F /path/to/configfile`, but this will require me to run ssh command each time, I am expecting a persistent configuration, so that it can be affected by other ssh related commands as well, such as `git`.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand which is your problem, why can't you simply edit your file `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: @delca85, sorry I didn't make it clear, the ~/.ssh/config is currently is a folder, and it was created by someone else for other usage, and because it is been used in a lot places, including scripts, it's hard to just rename it or move it to other places, so I want to keep the the directory ~/.ssh/config/ directory, and also have a ssh config file, I tried to edit ~/.ssh/config file, it will delete my folder named ~/.ssh/config/, and replace it as a file, then I will lose all of contents in ~/.ssh/config/, hope this make sense.

Comment: Found this answer : http://superuser.com/a/912281

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/912281) found on SuperUser :

### Environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`:

From Git version 2.3.0, you can use the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example" git clone example
```

Note that `-i` can sometimes be overridden by your config file, in which case, you should give SSH an empty config file, like this:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null" git clone example
```

### Configuration `core.sshCommand`:

From Git version 2.10.0, you can configure this per repo or globally, so you don't have to set the environment variable any more!

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null"
git pull
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple :

Make a sim link of your config file in another directory.

First step :
create a file (root mode)  in /etc/ssh/my_git_project/config

Second step (user mode) :

```
ln -s /etc/ssh/my_git_project/myhosts_config ~/.ssh/config
```

Comment: Please, when posting answers be more affirmative and don't include questions. As such your answer has been identified as Not An Answer by a bot that scans for low quality answers. Flagged as a false positive now but....

Comment: Not sure if this answer is specific to git but the question might need an answer that cover all other potential applications that might use ssh as well.